# Stuck in MYSQL mysqli fetch row

Tags: php, mysql

In my mysql database table `users`, there's a field `grpID`, with a value of one of `G00, G01, G02, G03`

What I am trying to do is check user's grpID to decide whether he/she has an authority to access to some pages.

So here's what I tried:

```
$isadmin = false;
function evalLoggedUser($conx,$id,$u,$p){
    $sql = "SELECT grpID FROM users WHERE userID='$id' AND userName='$u' AND userPW='$p' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows > 0){
        $userLvl = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        if ($userLvl[0]=="G00") {
            echo "isadmin set to true CONFIRM";
            $isadmin=true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I have a file with the above code named `check_status.php`

And in my `index.php` I have this code:

```
include_once("htconfig/check_status.php");
if($isadmin) {
echo "final confirmation";
}
```

Okay now, when I test this as a user with grpID `G00`, I do get the first echo, `isadmin set to true CONFIRM`. That proves that that isadmin is set to true, but I don't get the second echo inside the if clause...
I am struggling with this for couple hours... help please!

Comment: Not part of your issue but you should be using prepared statements and binding your parameters (`$id`, `$u`).

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Instead of using an if statement to check if there are any rows, why not use a fetch method on the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable scope:

```
$isadmin = false; // global scope
function evalLoggedUser(...) {
   ...
   $isadmin = true; // function LOCAL scope.
}
```

You're setting `true` on a completely different variable. you want this instead:

```
function evalLoggedUser(...) {
   global $isadmin; // make the local $isadmin point at the global version
   $isadmin = true;  // set the global variable's value.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the function you need to add:

```
$isadmin = false;
function evalLoggedUser($conx,$id,$u,$p){
    global $isadmin;
```